# Fetch multiple secrets from keyvault dynamically via yaml with prefix

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a deployment yaml which fetches multiple secrets from an azure keyvault.
This yaml is being used to deploy to multiple stages, every stage with its own keyvault and values.

The issue is that every stage has a different number of secrets,
so i would like to fetch all secrets containing a specific prefix (i only know the prefix, not the rest of the secret name at time of deployment) dynamically and ideally pass these secrets to my code in a dictionary or some sort of collection.

Is this scenario even possible? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: This yaml is being used to deploy to multiple stages, every stage with its own keyvault and values. >  Can you add your yaml script in your question, so I can check how are you passing the key vault secret variables?

Comment: hi @SiddheshDesai,
i guess the question is how would i pass those keyvault secret variables... i need guidance on how to correctly do that

Comment: You can store multiple secrets from your Key vault in a Variable group. With variable group> you can call all the secrets stored as a variable across multiple pipelines within your Azure DevOps project without the need to reference them again in every yaml script. Refer here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash#set-a-secret-variable-in-a-variable-group

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? If yes, I can share you the steps as an answer!

Comment: unfortuantely no, i would like to not use that since it would mean changes were i would need to involve other departments

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, By what I understand, You are fetching multiple secrets of qa, dev, prod stages stored in your key vault to in your yaml script  > And different secrets have specific prefix, qa-secret, prod-secret, and you want to reference this secrets while deployment ?

Comment: no, i'm fetching secrets for credentials to different endpoints... one stage talks to more endpoints than the other stages. The names of these secrets all have the same prefix.

And i would like to reference these secrets (in some sort of collection) on while deploying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252409/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-heycaptain).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on chat:-

In order to reference the secrets from your repository to your yaml script in name value pairs dynamically you can make use of `Get-Content` command let of **Powershell** to read the content of your secrets and then store them in a name value pairs.

```yaml
  
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- main

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

steps:

- script: echo Hello, world!

displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  

- script: |

echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.

echo See https://aka.ms/yaml

displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

  
  

- task: PowerShell@2

inputs:

targetType: 'inline'

script: |

$prefix = 'secret'

$secrets = @{}

Get-ChildItem -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/keyvaultsecrets" -Filter "${prefix}*" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

$name = $_.Name

$value = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$secrets[$name] = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($value))

}

Write-Host "Secrets found: $($secrets.Keys -join ', ')"

# pass $secrets to your code in Azure DevOps as environment variables or arguments
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can directly fetch the secrets from your Azure key vault with the `az keyvault secret list` and then loop over it to fetch the secrets by secretid in name:value pairs.

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- main

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2

inputs:

azureSubscription: '<subscription/serviceconnection>'

scriptType: 'bash'

scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'

inlineScript: |

prefix='qa-secret'

kv_name='siliconkeyvault098'

az login --service-principal -u "<client-id>" -p "client-secret" --tenant "<tenant-id>"

secrets=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $kv_name --query "[?starts_with(id, '$prefix')].{name:id}" -o tsv)

while IFS=$'\t' read -r name id

do

value=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name $kv_name --id $id --query "value" -o tsv)

echo "$name=$value"

# pass $name and $value to your code in Azure DevOps as environment variables or arguments

done <<< "$secrets"
```

**Output:-**

[image]